# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(X \geq k) = E[X]$ for any discrete random variable with nonnegative values.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The hint for this problem that is given in the book is to write $P(X \geq k)$ as $\sum_{i=k}^{\infty} P(X = i)$ and then switch the order of summation but I have no idea how to continue from there. This would leave me with $$ \sum_{i=k}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P(X = i)$$.

Comment: The sum over $k$ should be to the left of the sum over $i$.

Answer (score 1):

Great, now try to rearrange terms in your last expression to equate that sum to the definition of expectation for such random variables.
$$E[X] = \sum_{j=1}^\infty j P(X=j).$$